# Ruby: Create new string at every replacement

Tags: ruby

How to create a list of strings with only one replace of matched pattern in ruby.

For example:

The given string is "aaaazzzazazaaaazzzazaaaazz". I need to replace "aaaa" with "A".
So I would get a such list:

- "Azzzazazaaaazzzazaaaazz"
- "aaaazzzazazAzzzazaaaazz"
- "aaaazzzazazaaaazzzazAzz"

  ```
   s = gets.strip
   stor="aaaa"
   sforr="A"
   a = s.split(stor)
   (a.length-1).times { |x| puts a[0..x].join(stor)+sforr+
                                 a[x+1..a.count-1].join(stor) }
  ```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have already tried, why that didn't work, what you've tried to mitigate that and generally, where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a block:

```
str = "aaaazzzazazaaaazzzazaaaazz"
str.scan(/aaaa/) { |m| puts "#{$`}A#{$'}" }
```

Output:

```
Azzzazazaaaazzzazaaaazz
aaaazzzazazAzzzazaaaazz
aaaazzzazazaaaazzzazAzz
```

`` $` `` and `$'` are [global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html), referencing the strings to the left and to the right of the last match.